# How to use 2 different git repos (mutually ignoring each other files) in one common folders tree?

Tags: git

I need to use 2 different git repos in the same folder tree.
Let's say I have the following local file tree :

**Workspace**

**Folder 1**
*Folder A*
File x1
File y1
... any other files ...
*Folder B*
File z1
... any other files ...

**Folder 2**
*Folder A*
File x2
File y2
... any other files ...
*Folder B*
File z2
... any other files ...

............
and so on
............

**Folder n**
*Folder A*
File xn
File yn
... any other files ...
*Folder B*
File zn
... any other files ...

I want all the files under the n "Folder A" handled in one git "Repo A". The "Repo A" would be set to ignore all the files under the n "Folder B".
Symmetrically, I want the files under the "Folder B" handled in another git "Repo B". The "Repo B" would be set to ignore all the files under the n "Folder A".

Here are some examples of usecases :

- when I add a file to a "Folder A", I want this file to be detected as a new file by git "Repo A" and not "Repo B".
- I want to be able to clone only "Repo B" for instance, so that I get only the file tree with B files.

Here are some precisions about the nature of files in those repos (answer to LeGEC comment) :

- Folders 1, 2, ... n are dedicated to the n functions of the system I am developing. In other words, the folder tree is my functional breakdown.
- Files in git Repo A are Matlab script and functions. Let's say these scripts are tests of the function I am developing.
- Files in git Repo B are results of the tests, sometime with post-processing/analysis which allow to state if the function has been correctly implemented.
  Indeed checking out two versions of Repo A and Repo B which would not be consistent would not make sense. Nevertheless, the nature of A and B files is really different (tests for Repo A, verification evidence for Repo B), and it makes sense to keep these files in separate repos.

My question is simple : how to do that ?
I use git clients like Tortoise or SourceTree and I want the more transparent solution for users because this configuration will be used by non git specialist, most of them not very familiar with advanced git functions.

I have been looking for some technical solutions to my need, but so far without success :

- I have understood it is impossible to have 2 different .gitignore files at the root of my local repo ("Workspace" in my example), but it might be possible to use .git/info/exclude instead.
- I have read ([here](https://www.vikingsoftware.com/blog/multiple-git-repositories-in-the-same-tree/)) it is possible to set/unset variables such as GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE but it seems it is necessary to set/unset these variables when I want to deal with Repo A or Repo B. It does not seem compatible with a transparent and easy solution for basic users.

In advance, thank you for your help!

Comment: Submodules+symlinks?

Comment: Can you give more information on the nature of `FolderA`s and `FolderB`s ? for example: is it code with interdependencies ? or is it really two independant contents ? Does "checking out `FolderB`s" *also* require "checking out a precise version of `FolderA`s" for the global content to make sense ?

Comment: Could you write some YAML showing the folder/file structure you want, and to the right of each file name write which repo you want to have the file in.

Comment: @LeGEC I added some precisions in order to clarify my question. Hope it helps. Thank you !

Comment: "It does not seem compatible with a transparent and easy solution for basic users." << Your whole setup seems not really transparant and easy.

Comment: Why? Sounds like an xy problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are related I would suggest to commit them together.

If you expect users to not edit the code and just use it, you may choose a way to generate some release versions of your program (if it's Matlab scripts: probably a tarball of `FolderA`s ?) and distribute that.

If you expect your users to fiddle with the code, it's probably a good thing to leave the tests together with the code anyway.